# Sending an Array of Strings using Message Passing Interface

Tags: mpi, mpj-express

I would like to send an array of strings from the master to a slave thread using Messgae Passing Interface (MPI).
i.e. String [] str = new String [10] 
str[0]= "XXX" ... etc

How can I do that while avoiding to send each of the elements in this array as a chain of characters?

I succeeded to send an array of integers in one send operation ... but I don't know how to do that when it is about an array of strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Java, but I'll give you the C answer.  The concepts -- particularly the two approaches one might take to solve this - are the same in any language, though.

Imagine if this were a simple c-string (some characters terminated with '\0').  There are  two approaches:

1. over-provision memory and receive up to some limit,
2. or send a message indicating how much data to expect.

Do you have a maximum length?  (e.g. PATH_MAX or something like that).  If you do not need every byte of memory, you could do

```
MPI_Send(str, strlen(str), MPI_CHAR, slave_rank, slave_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and you'd pair that with

```
MPI_Recv(str, MAX_LENGTH, MPI_CHAR, master_rank, slave_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

If you don't like having slop at the end, you'll have to do it in two messages:

```
len=strlen(str) + 1;  /* +1 for the NULL byte */
MPI_Send(&len, 1, MPI_INT, slave_rank, slave_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
MPI_Send(str, strlen(str), MPI_CHAR, slave_rank, slave_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

and you'd match that with

```
MPI_Recv(&len, 1, MPI_INT, master_rank, slave_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
payload= malloc(len);
MPI_Recv(&payload, len, MPI_CHAR, master_rank, slave_tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: The question is about an MPI implementation in Java.

Comment: The idea is still the same unless your Java MPI implementation has some fancy String object. You'll just have to change `strlen(str)` to `str.length()`.

Comment: Hristo, thanks for pointing that out to me.  I edited my answer to make it clear that I don't know anything about Java

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your detailed answers ....
Yesterday, I discovered a very easy way to do that in java ...
You just need to transform your String Arrayy to an Object Array and then you send the length of the Array object :
      MPI.COMM_WORLD.Isend(ObjectArray, index, ObjectArray.length, MPI.OBJECT, rank, tag);

Comment: @StudyLearn, wish I could have seen your comment before I punched all that code in my answer :)

Comment: Oh sorry really ... My answer below.

Comment: The question is about sending an ARRAY of strings, not just one string

Answer (score 3):

Sending arrays of strings, especially if of varying sizes, is quite an involving process. There are several options but the most MPI-friendly one is to use the packing and unpacking facilities of MPI, exposed in mpiJava as `Comm.Pack`, `Comm.Unpack`, and `Comm.Pack_size`.

You could do something of the sort:

#### Sender

```java
byte[][] bytes = new byte[nStr][];
int[] lengths = new int[nStr];

int bufLen = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Pack_size(1, MPI.INT);

bufLen += MPI.COMM_WORLD.Pack_size(nStr, MPI.INT);

for (int i = 0; i < nStr; i++) {
   bytes[i] = str[i].getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
   lengths[i] = bytes[i].length;
   bufLen += MPI.COMM_WORLD.Pack_size(lengths[i], MPI.BYTE);
}

byte[] buf = new byte[bufLen];
int position = 0;

int nStrArray[] = new int[1];
nStrArray[0] = nStr;

position = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Pack(nStrArray, 0, 1, MPI.INT,
                               buf, position);

position = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Pack(lengths, 0, nStr, MPI.INT,
                               buf, position);

for (int i = 0; i < nStr; i++) {
   position = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Pack(bytes[i], 0, lengths[i], MPI.BYTE,
                                  buf, position);
}

MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(buf, 0, bufLen, MPI.PACKED, rank, 0);
```

Having string lengths in an auxiliary array and packing it at the beginning of the message simplifies the receiver logic.

#### Receiver

Assumes that the sender is rank 0.

```java
Status status = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Probe(0, 0);
int bufLen = status.Get_count(MPI.PACKED);

byte[] buf = new byte[bufLen];

MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(buf, 0, bufLen, MPI.PACKED, status.source, status.tag);

int position = 0;

int nStrArray[] = new int[1];

position = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Unpack(buf, position,
                                 nStrArray, 0, 1, MPI.INT);

int nStr = nStrArray[0];
int lengths[] = new int[nStr];

position = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Unpack(buf, position,
                                 lengths, 0, nStr, MPI.INT);

String[] str = new String[nStr];

for (int i = 0; i < nStr; i++) {
   byte[] bytes = new byte[lengths[i]];

   position = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Unpack(buf, position,
                                    bytes, 0, lengths[i], MPI.BYTE);
   str[i] = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I don't have MPJ Express installed and my Java knowledge is very limited. The code is based on the [mpiJava specification](http://www.open-mpi.org/papers/mpi-java-spec/mpiJava-spec.pdf), the [MPJ Express JavaDocs](http://mpj-express.org/docs/javadocs/index.html), and some [examples](http://www.gm.fh-koeln.de/ehses/avs/AVS_3_IbisMPJ.pdf) found on the Internet.

Comment: Oh that's really an intelligent way .. though I found a shorter answer, I learnt a nice way to pack and unpack data sent to receiver :) I will include it in my implementation :)